# Powershell automate input

Tags: powershell, cmd, automation, download

Need to automate user input for software installation. In ps it self i can easily run just the setup command for starting the download of my application. But using scripts it won't?
This is a part of my code first i tried to unzip the folder(works). after that i need to "write" setup to start the installation. after that i need a bunch of y and n inputs. i want to make this fully automatic that we only need to run the ps. Can someone help me with how to run this "commands" ?

```
> Expand-Archive -LiteralPath somepath -DestinationPath somepath 
> cd c:\skyspark\bin\ 
> cmd setup  y  y  n y  8080  y  n
```

Comment: Please copy and paste, as text, the code you are trying to make work into the question. Use the {} icon in the editor to mark it as code. I assume that your `setup` executable accepts responses from the command line. Does your `setup` executable do that? If this is a publicly available application, telling us what it is might help.

Comment: Its made to run from the command prompt. Navigating to the file and entering `setup` will start the installation. Im not able to do this in a ps script. And its an private software called skyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cmd` will start `cmd.exe` which is probably not what you want. If `setup` is actually `setup.exe`, then simply run it as-is.

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath somepath -DestinationPath somepath 
Set-Location -Path c:\skyspark\bin\ 
& setup.exe  y  y  n y  8080  y  n
```

Comment: Nice, but to be more specific: `cmd` will enter _an interactive session_ (unless a command is passed _via `/c`_, but, as you state, there's no reason not to just invoke the executable directly in this case).

Comment: The "y" and "n" inputs or the user inputs which i'm trying to automate are still not running.

Comment: Being able to automate responses to setup.exe depends on how setup.exe is written. Is your setup.exe a private program to which you have source code? Or, is your setup.exe a commercially available installer program?